# When does an answer become community wiki?

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

I made about [12 revisions to my Answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency/218017#218017) when I noticed that the answer became a community wiki.

The change to CW was automatic and it's connected to one of my edits.

What causes this?

Would a rollback of some of the revisions make my Answer normal again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What causes this?

[What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Posts enter community wiki mode when one of the following happens:

- The body of the post has been edited by at least five (**5**) different users.
- The post has been edited ten (**10**) times by the original owner.

> Would a rollback of some of the revisions make my Answer normal again?

No, once it has gone CW, it is CW for good.

Comment: Thank you so much! So I should definitely think about making excess edits myself on my own questions. I didn't know it would turn a question CW. As a user with low reputation, even an excellent question (which may gain you 5 upvotes the next months) will no longer gain you reputation, so in fact _you're shooting yourself in the foot_!! If a diamond mod reads this, can I please have my CW status revoked on that one? Thanks. http://serverfault.com/questions/244944/linux-ata-errors-translating-to-a-device-name/426561 I would definitely not shed a tear when this silly CW thing goes away one day.

Comment: `once it has gone CW, it is CW for good` Good for what/where/who ? I cannot see any reason why community could take ownership when they have even not take time to answer the OP and without upvoting the OP nor Answer...is it because spelling corrections brings to CW ?